# Replace CSS class to HTML tag

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I have this:

```
<span class="ld-nowrap"> 20th century’s </span>
```

and i want to get this:

```
<em> 20th century’s </em>
```

using python 3 and BeautifulSoap

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.replace_with()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) to replace the tag inside the soup:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<span class="ld-nowrap"> 20th century’s </span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

# 1. find the <span> tag to replace:
span = soup.find("span", class_="ld-nowrap")

# 2. create new <em> tag with the same contents as <span>
em = soup.new_tag("em")
em.contents = span.contents

# 3. replace the tag inside the tree
span.replace_with(em)
print(soup)
```

Prints:

```html
<em> 20th century’s </em>
```

---

EDIT: To replace multiple tags:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<span class="ld-nowrap"> 20th century’s </span>
<span class="ld-nowrap"> 21th century’s </span>
<span> No replace </span>
<span class="ld-nowrap"> 22th century’s </span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for span in soup.find_all("span", class_="ld-nowrap"):
    em = soup.new_tag("em")
    em.contents = span.contents
    span.replace_with(em)

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```html
<em> 20th century’s </em>
<em> 21th century’s </em>
<span> No replace </span>
<em> 22th century’s </em>
```

Comment: Ok, but how to replace all span tags? I mean if i need to use find_all
    span = new_soup.find_all("span", class_="ld-nowrap")

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that?

```
soup = '<span class="ld-nowrap"> 20th century’s </span>'

for x in soup.find_all('span', class_= 'ld-nowrap'):
    print('<em>'+x.text+'</em>')
```